# React JS - Modify application based on a user role

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to implement an application with two user roles (reader, editor). What's the best way to change application behavior based on user role?
I can think of making two copy of app (one for reader and one for editor) and redirect user to corresponding path after auhtentication.
But in this way application will be hard to maintain.

Is it possible to pass a parameter to a React component so it'll change it's look but at the same time prevent user from modifying parameter string or the component? Maybe server side rendering could help with it?

Comment: Just put a check in there. i.e.  `if (user.isEditor)`  This is regardless of it being a React app, btw.

Comment: In this way user will be able to set isEditor by himself and change app behavior...
or you mean that I also should restrict action on a server side. So even if user will get markup he still won't be able to get data that he's not supposed to get?

Comment: You store the user's status on the server side, then pass it to the front, where you store it in Redux state if you're using that.  This is pretty standard stuff.

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it. What if Reader changes Redux state and get Editor permissions?

Comment: He'll get editor permissions on the **client side**. I can try to delete your comment in the HTML of the page I'm looking at, that doesn't mean I gained full SO admin permissions. Also, changing stuff in React in the browser isn't that easy.